# Delete character in a string

Tags: r

I want to delete the penultimate number in the string

Example

initial database

```
num
23001
662001
11001
```

I want to

```
num
2301
66201
1101
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried, or any errors you are getting.

Comment: @MathieuLenormand, your original post asks how to delete the penultimate number in the string, and the answer you accepted __assumes__ that the penultimate number is always _0_. I just want to clarify what exactly you're asking so other SO user's find this question useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick answer, where I use `gsub` to change `00` to `0`.

```
num <- c(23001,662001,11001)
as.numeric(gsub('00','0',as.character(num)))
# [1]  2301 66201  1101
```